# Symlink across local volumes in webroot?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, symlink

I am looking for a good short-term solution to storage space concerns on my website. Currently, I have all uploaded files (flash video, images, etc.) inside the 'files' directory in my web root (/home/account/public_html/files).

That directory is located on my high-speed main hard drive (two mirrored 74 GB 15k SCSI drive).

I have another drive with much more capacity (300 GB), but spinning at 10k rpm (so still fast, but not as good for random reads/writes as the main drive). The entire drive is mounted at /backup

Right now I'm just using it as a backup volume. I would like to create a symlink from my /home/account/public_html/files folder to /backup/files, and have all files reside on the second drive.

However, if someone accesses a file at http://www.example.com/files/filename.jpg, would it still work if I symlinked to the second drive? (Basically, would Apache/PHP automatically know to follow the symlink for that directory?).

I'm beginning to run out of space on the main drive, and I can't get the budget to upgrade. I'm running CentOS 5.3, Apache 2.2.x, PHP 5.2.13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `Options FollowSymLinks` set globally, or for that virtual host, or for the parent directory, then yes, Apache will know to follow the symlink.

Comment: Do you know if that's enabled by default? I will check httpd.conf, just to be sure...

Comment: This is probably distro specific, and I don't have access to a CentOS box right now, but on Red Hat Enterprise 5.5 (on which CentOS is based) it is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is using alias in Apache.  For example:

```
alias /files /backups/files
```